# Different build numbers for the same Mathematica version

Tags: version-12.1

Recently I downloaded a trial version of Mathematica 12.1.1 installation package for linux. Some time afterwards I had to download the same package again, and then I noticed that the package's md5 sum has changed. After installing both packages, I see that they have different Release IDs: the first one is '12.1.1.0 (6938436, 2020060901)', while the second one is '12.1.1.0 (6959353, 2020061902)'.

What is the difference between those packages? Were some important bugs fixed, features added? There was (as far as I could see) no announcement about a new version, as was when 12.1.1 was released, for example, and no changelog is available - packages were just silently replaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I received the following in an e-mail.

```
New Mathematica 12.1.1 Files

Due to customer feedback, we discovered a bug that caused unexpected 
cell style changes for certain keyboard input. We have fixed the problem, 
and new Mathematica 12.1.1 files are now available in the Wolfram User 
Portal.

If you have already installed Mathematica 12.1.1, we encourage you to 
download the new files and reinstall Version 12.1.1.

We are sorry for any inconvenience this may have caused. Please contact 
us if you have any questions. 

Best regards,
 
Wolfram Research
Customer Support
```